# Problema em fazer o Bind com Partial View no Asp.Net Framework MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bind

Fiz um app em .net framework mvc em C#, usando partial view...
O problema que estou encontrando, é que parece que o Bind da janela principal não está funcionando. 
O Bind parece funcionar só com as Modais.
Tenho a janela principal, que é uma partial view, chamada Sistema.
Tenho outras duas partial views, que são duas modais: Endereco e Documento, que são chamadas quando clico no botão da janela principal. Quando salvo a modal Endereco, por exemplo, e envio os dados, funciona, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando preencho os dados da janela principal, que é a partial view Sistema, e dou submit, no lado do servidor, na controller, parece que o Bind não funciona, aparece null, conforme imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Documento e Endereco são as modais, cujo Bind funciona perfeitamente. E o Sistema é a janela principal, que não funciona o Bind. Os 3 são partial View.

Minha controller:

```
    // GET: Sistemas/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var listEndereco = db.Endereco.ToList();
        listEndereco.Insert(0, new Endereco() { Caminho = "-- Por favor selecione --" });
        ViewBag.Enderecos = new SelectList(listEndereco, "Id", "Caminho"); //showing the list of drivers on edit page



        var listDocumento = db.Documento.ToList();
        listDocumento.Insert(0, new Documento() { Nome = "-- Por favor selecione --" });
        ViewBag.Documentos = new SelectList(listDocumento, "Id", "Nome"); //showing the list of drivers on edit page



        return View();
    }

    // POST: Sistemas/Create
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, habilite as propriedades específicas às quais você quer se associar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, veja https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Sistema,Endereco,Documento")] CreateSistemasModel sistema)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if ((sistema.Endereco != null) || (sistema.Documento != null) || (sistema.Sistema != null))
            {
                if ((sistema.Endereco != null))
                {
                   
                    db.Endereco.Add(sistema.Endereco);
                   // sistema.Sistema.Indice = (string)ViewData["Indice"];
                    
                }
                else
                if (sistema.Documento != null)
                {
                    db.Documento.Add(sistema.Documento);
                    
                }
                else
                if (sistema.Sistema != null)
                {
                    db.Sistema.Add(sistema.Sistema);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                var listEndereco = db.Endereco.ToList();
                listEndereco.Insert(0, new Endereco() { Caminho = "-- Por favor selecione --" });
                ViewBag.Enderecos = new SelectList(listEndereco, "Id", "Caminho"); //showing the list of drivers on edit page



                var listDocumento = db.Documento.ToList();
                listDocumento.Insert(0, new Documento() { Nome = "-- Por favor selecione --" });
                ViewBag.Documentos = new SelectList(listDocumento, "Id", "Nome"); //showing the list of drivers on edit page
                return View(sistema);
            }
        }
        ViewBag.EnderecoId = new SelectList(db.Endereco, "Id", "Caminho", sistema.Sistema.EnderecoId);
        ViewBag.DocumentoId = new SelectList(db.Documento, "Id", "Nome", sistema.Sistema.DocumentoId);
        return View(sistema);
    }
```

**As models:**

Sistema:

```
 public class Sistema
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Indice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Pasta { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? EnderecoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EnderecoId")]

    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? DocumentoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocumentoId")]

}
```

Documento:

```
public class Documento
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Endereço:

```
public class Endereco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Caminho { get; set; }
}
```

Criei uma model para reunir as outras models:

```
 public class CreateSistemasModel
{
    public Sistema Sistema { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public Documento Documento { get; set; }

}
```

**As Views:**

***Create:***

```
@model Globais.Models.ViewModels.CreateSistemasModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Formulário de Cadastro de Sistema";
}

    <script src="~/Scripts/Site.js"></script>
    <h3 class="cabecalho titulo">&nbsp;Formulário de Cadastro de Sistema </h3>

@*----Carrega formulário  Sistema---*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sistemas",FormMethod.Post))
{

    //@await Html.PartialAsync()
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Sistemas/Formulario.cshtml", Model);
        
        //Script que serve para manter os dados no formulário principal ao chamar uma modal e salvar os dados dela.
    <script>
        debugger;

        carregarDadosCreateSistema();
    </script>
}

@*----Carrega Modais---*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sistemas"))
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Sistemas/Modais.cshtml", Model)
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

***Formulário Principal:*** *Formulario.cshtml*

```
@model Globais.Models.ViewModels.CreateSistemasModel

<hr />
<form controller="Sistema" action="Create" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sistema.Indice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sistema.Indice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Indice" } })
              

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sistema.Indice, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-6" })
          
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sistema.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sistema.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Nome" } })

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sistema.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-6" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sistema.EnderecoId, "Endereço", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.DropDownList("Enderecos", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select-button col-md-6", @id = "Endereco" })

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  glyphicon glyphicon-plus buttonAdd " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enderecoModal" data-whatever="getbootstrap"
                            onclick="carregar()" data-placement="top"
                            title="Clique para adicionar um Endereço"
                            style="margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:15px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px"></button>

                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sistema.EnderecoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-6" })
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sistema.DocumentoId, "Documento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.DropDownList("Documentos", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select-button col-md-6", @id = "Documento" })


                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  glyphicon glyphicon-plus buttonAdd " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#documentoModal" data-whatever="getbootstrap"
                            onclick="gravar()" data-placement="top"
                            title="Clique para adicionar uma localidade"
                            style="margin-bottom:30px; margin-left:15px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px"></button>

                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sistema.DocumentoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-6" })
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sistema.Pasta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sistema.Pasta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Pasta" } })

            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sistema.Pasta, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-6" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">

        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
            <button type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save control-label "><span class="textoIcone">Salvar</span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
            @* <button class="btn btn-info bi bi-reply control-label" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index")';return false;"><span class="textoIcone">Voltar</span></button>*@
            <button class="  bi-arrow-return-left btn btn-info " control-label" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index")';return false;"><span class="textoIcone">Voltar</span></button>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

***Modais:*** *Modais.cshtml*

```
@model Globais.Models.ViewModels.CreateSistemasModel

@*-----------------MODAIS:------------------------*@

@*----Modal Edereco----*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sistemas"))
{
 
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/ViewModals/EnderecoModal.cshtml", Model)
}

@*----Modal Documento----*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Sistemas"))
{
   
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/ViewModals/DocumentoModal.cshtml", Model)
}
```

***Documento:*** *DocumentoModal.cshtml*

```
@model Globais.Models.ViewModels.CreateSistemasModel


<form controller="Sistema" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-update="documentoFormCreate" data-ajax-complete="OnComplete">

    @*----Montando a modal-----*@
    <div id="documentoModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Cadastrar Documento</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" onclick="limparCamposDocumento()">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>


                @*Formulário*@
            <div class="modal-body" id="documentoFormCreate">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Documento.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Documento.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Documento.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" onclick=" limparCamposDocumento()" class="btn btn-close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="textoIcone"><span class="textoIcone">Fechar</span></span></button>
                    <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="gravarCreateSistemas()" type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="textoIcone">Salvar</span></button>
                </div>




            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

***Endereço:*** *EnderecoModal.cshtml*

```
@model Globais.Models.ViewModels.CreateSistemasModel

<form controller="Sistema" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-update="enderecoFormCreate" data-ajax-complete="OnComplete">
    @*----Montando a modal-----*@
    <div id="enderecoModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Cadastrar Endereço</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" onclick="limparCamposEndereco()">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                @*Formulário*@
            <div class="modal-body" id="enderecoFormCreate">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Caminho, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Caminho, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-modal" } })

                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Caminho, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-md-12" })
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" onclick=" limparCamposEndereco()" class="btn btn-close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="textoIcone"><span class="textoIcone">Fechar</span></span></button>
                    <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="gravarCreateSistemas()" type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="textoIcone">Salvar</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Scripts:** *Site.js*

```
//Mantém os dados nos campos do create Sistema, após salvar a modal
//Salva no localstorage
function gravarCreateSistemas() {
    debugger
    localStorage.setItem("Nome", document.getElementById("Nome").value);
    localStorage.setItem("Indice", document.getElementById("Indice").value);
    localStorage.setItem("Endereco", document.getElementById("Endereco").value);
    localStorage.setItem("Documento", document.getElementById("Documento").value);

    localStorage.setItem("Pasta", document.getElementById("Pasta").value);
}

//Recarrega dados salvos do localstorage
function carregarDadosCreateSistema() {
    debugger
    document.getElementById("Nome").value = localStorage.getItem("Nome");
    document.getElementById("Indice").value = localStorage.getItem("Indice");
    document.getElementById("Endereco").value = localStorage.getItem("Endereco");
    document.getElementById("Documento").value = localStorage.getItem("Documento");
    document.getElementById("Pasta").value = localStorage.getItem("Pasta");
}
```

**Imagem da View:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui resolver!

Comment: O problema era que não se pode colocar o mesmo nome, mesmo sendo em minúsculo. Aqui:

 public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Sistema,Endereco,Documento")] CreateSistemasModel sis)

Antes estava assim:
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Sistema,Endereco,Documento")] CreateSistemasModel sistema)

Mesmo sendo em minúsculo, não pode colocar o mesmo nome da model: Sistema e sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!

**Corrigido:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Sistema,Endereco,Documento")] CreateSistemasModel sis)
```

**Como estava antes:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Sistema,Endereco,Documento")] CreateSistemasModel sistema)
```

Não se pode colocar o mesmo nome de uma das models, mesmo que seja em minúsculo. No caso, coloquei ali em minúsculo "sistema", sendo que uma das models é "Sistema". Troquei para sis, e agora está funcionando. :)

Demorei quase 3 dias para conseguir resolver. :')

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Minha vida é limitada demais. Não tenho tempo de fazer uma resposta que siga os padrões politicamente corretos. A resposta ta aí, é o que a casa oferece. Abraço!